# How to get transaction history without certain state

Tags: corda

I try to get transaction history on corda. 
I need to get the amount of the transaction for a certain period
My api for this :

```
@GET
@Path("transactions")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
fun gettransatcions(): List<StateAndRef<ContractState>> {

    val TODAY = Instant.now()
    val pagingSpec = PageSpecification(DEFAULT_PAGE_NUM, 100)
    val start = TODAY.minus(1, ChronoUnit.HOURS)
    val end = TODAY.plus(1, ChronoUnit.HOURS)

    val recordedBetweenExpression = QueryCriteria.TimeCondition(
            QueryCriteria.TimeInstantType.RECORDED,
            ColumnPredicate.Between(start, end))

    val criteria = QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(timeCondition = recordedBetweenExpression,status = Vault.StateStatus.ALL)
    val results = rpcOps.vaultQueryBy<ContractState>(criteria, paging = pagingSpec)
    val size = results.states.count()

    return rpcOps.vaultQueryBy<ContractState>().states
}
```

where:
val rpcOps: CordaRPCOps

I can explicitly specify States  for which to receive transactions like:

```
val criteria = VaultQueryCriteria(contractStateTypes = setOf(Cash.State::class.java, DealState::class.java))
```

but, I need to get transactions across **all states except for a certain**.

Have corda got any mechanism for this ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. Are you saying you're trying to exclude the outputs of a specific transaction(s) from your query? How are you selecting the  transaction(s) to exclude?

Comment: I want to get all transaction by selected states. I mean, i have for example 4 states :
(stateName1, stateName2, stateName3, stateName4 ). I need to get transactions by last mounth from stateName1 and stateName2.

Answer (score 0):

There is no type of query criteria that specifically *excludes* certain states. However, you can define a query criteria that specifically *includes* certain states, then combine that with your existing criteria using an `AND` composition:

```
val TODAY = Instant.now()
val pagingSpec = PageSpecification(DEFAULT_PAGE_NUM, 100)
val start = TODAY.minus(1, ChronoUnit.HOURS)
val end = TODAY.plus(1, ChronoUnit.HOURS)

val recordedBetweenExpression = QueryCriteria.TimeCondition(
        QueryCriteria.TimeInstantType.RECORDED,
        ColumnPredicate.Between(start, end))

val timeCriteria = QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(timeCondition = recordedBetweenExpression, status = Vault.StateStatus.ALL)
val typeCriteria = QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(contractStateTypes = setOf(State1::class.java, State2::class.java), status = Vault.StateStatus.ALL)
val combinedCriteria = timeCriteria.and(typeCriteria)
val results = rpcOps.vaultQueryBy<ContractState>(combinedCriteria, paging = pagingSpec)
```

This will retrieve all the states that meet both your time criteria and your type criteria.